# Is it possible to convert a Scratch project to an Android app?

Tags: javascript, java, android, html, mit-scratch

For those of you who don't know, Scratch (**scratch.mit.edu**) is a programming language based around connecting 'blocks' of code in order to create a project.

I have tried using a Scratch to HTML converter (**forkphorus.github.io**) in order to convert my Scratch code into HTML in order to see if the HTML code could be ported to Android. The Scratch converter has options to port all of the code (including the Scratch engine) into a single file that is playable on internet browsers. After converting the code to HTML, I followed the next step of the tutorial to pull the source code of the **forkphorus** (Scratch to HTML) and use **Adobe PhoneGap** in order to convert the code into an .apk file. Once I tried to install the .apk file, however, it was stuck on the loading screen.

I have a feeling that it is possible to convert Scratch code into an Android app but I just don't know how. If anyone has any suggestions, I would be grateful...

Project I am trying to convert: **Bounce 1.3.1**

Snippet of Scratch project code in HTML, if it helps:

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
    .forkphorus-root {
  position: relative;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  width: 480px;
  height: 360px;
  font-size: 10px;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: black;
  overflow: hidden;
  user-select: none;
}

.forkphorus-root > * {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  transform: translateZ(0);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: This code is just CSS styling

Answer (score 2):

Just use HTMLifier. You can use it here: https://sheeptester.github.io/htmlifier/

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't convert Scratch projects to Android apps. But if you want to create an Android app, you can perhaps use a framework like Kivy in Python.

Answer (score 0):

## Yes, it is absolutely possible!

Just go to the scratch project url, then type “fullscreen” at the end:

`https://scratch.mit.edu/projects/888787589/` to `https://scratch.mit.edu/projects/888787589/fullscreen`

Now go to a website like
https://websitetoapk.com/
Or [search on Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=free%20online%20website%20to%20apk%20converter) for a website to APK convertor. There are plenty of awesome free online ones. (Most will require an account, though).

Paste your modified Scratch project URL into the converter, then create your app!

Or, you can use the outdated packager here:

https://forkphorus.github.io/packager/

Or use this:

https://sheeptester.github.io/htmlifier/

I hope this helps!